# Is it possible to upload a directory of files with XHR?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, directory, xmlhttprequest

I'm seeing that I can select a folder with an input, but it appears that I have no way of recursing through the files in that folder to upload them via XHR.

Comment: If you select a folder, what does the debugger (watch) say?

Answer (score 1):

Yes*

```
<input type=file name=files id=files multiple>
```

* only works on very recent browsers.  You should get array of the data you'd normally get from a single file upload element and from there you're off to the races with HTML5

Other than that you're stuck with something like:
http://swfupload.org/

And by recent I mean it's working in Firefox 8, Safari 5.1 and Google Chrome 15 all installed on my Mac.  But these are the latest versions.